# Android: Encrypt String, send via HTTPS and Decrypt String problem

Tags: android, string, https

I have to Encrypt a String to send via HTTPS to a server. Then, on server side, I have to Decrypt the string and used it.

I used this code in both sides:

```
public class SimpleCrypto {

public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {

    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());

    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());

    return toHex(result);
}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {

    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());

    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);

    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);

    return new String(result);
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {

    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

    sr.setSeed(seed);

    kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available

    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();

    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();

    return raw;
}


private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);

    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

    return decrypted;
}

public static String toHex(String txt) {

    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}
public static String fromHex(String hex) {

    return new String(toByte(hex));
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {

    int len = hexString.length()/2;

    byte[] result = new byte[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();

    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {

    if (buf == null)
        return "";

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }

    return result.toString();
}

private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {

    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
}

}
```

On android, using "123456789" as a seed the rawKey give me:

[99, 51, -103, -58, 81, -52, 90, -103, -114, 70, -128, -25, -105, -124, -128, -67]

But on Server side, using the same seed, give me:

[-52, 103, 4, 60, 123, -49, -11, -18, -91, 86, 107, -39, -79, -13, -57, 79]

I can't understand why. Is diferent the javax.crypto.KeyGenerator on Android?, I'm making something bad?

Please, I need some help.

Thank you very much

Sorry for my poor english

-----------------------------UPDATE--------------------------------------------------------

This is my new code:

```
public class DesEncrypter {

    public static final int SALT_LENGTH = 20;
    public static final int PBE_ITERATION_COUNT = 1024;

    private static final String RANDOM_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";
    private static final String PBE_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC";
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";


    public byte[] encrypt(String password, String cleartext) {

        byte[] encryptedText = null;

        try {
            byte[] salt = "dfghjklpoiuytgftgyhj".getBytes();

            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, PBE_ITERATION_COUNT, 256);

            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC");

            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            byte[] key = secret.getEncoded();

            Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);   

            byte[] iv = generateIv();

            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);

            encryptedText = encryptionCipher.doFinal(cleartext.getBytes());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return encryptedText;
    }

    public String decrypt(String password, byte[] encryptedText) {

        String cleartext = "";

        try {
            byte[] salt = "dfghjklpoiuytgftgyhj".getBytes();

            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, PBE_ITERATION_COUNT, 256);

            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC");

            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            byte[] key = secret.getEncoded();

            Cipher decryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

            byte[] iv = generateIv();

            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            decryptionCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);

            byte[] decryptedText = decryptionCipher.doFinal(encryptedText);

            cleartext =  new String(decryptedText); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return cleartext;
    }   

    private byte[] generateIv() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance(RANDOM_ALGORITHM);

        byte[] iv = new byte[16];

        random.nextBytes(iv);

        return iv;
    }

}
```

----------------------------FINALL CODE WORKING ON ANDROID!--------------------------------

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class DesEncrypter {

    public static final int SALT_LENGTH = 20;
    public static final int PBE_ITERATION_COUNT = 200; //1024;

    private static final String PBE_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC";

    //algoritmo / modo / relleno 
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    byte[] iv = "1234567890asdfgh".getBytes();

    byte[] salt = "dfghjklpoiuytgftgyhj".getBytes();

    public byte[] encrypt(String password, String cleartext) {

        byte[] encryptedText = null;

        try {


            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, PBE_ITERATION_COUNT, 256);

            //Factoria para crear la SecretKey, debemos indicar el Algoritmo
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBE_ALGORITHM);

            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

            //Creamos una llave;
            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            //Obtenemos la llave, solo informativo
            byte[] key = secret.getEncoded();

            //La clase Cipher, se usa para cifrar mediante algoritmos de  clave simétrica
            Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);   

            //byte[] iv = generateIv();

            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            //Accion, SecretKey, parameter specification for an initialization vector
            encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);

            //Realizamos el cifrado
            encryptedText = encryptionCipher.doFinal(cleartext.getBytes());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return encryptedText;
    }

    public String decrypt(String password, byte[] encryptedText) {

        String cleartext = "";

        try {

            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, PBE_ITERATION_COUNT, 256);

            //Factoria para crear la SecretKey, debemos indicar el Algoritmo
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBE_ALGORITHM);

            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

            //Creamos una llave;
            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            //Obtenemos la llave, solo informativo
            byte[] key = secret.getEncoded();

            //La clase Cipher, se usa para cifrar mediante algoritmos de  clave simétrica
            Cipher decryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

            //byte[] iv = generateIv();

            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            //Accion, SecretKey, parameter specification for an initialization vector
            decryptionCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);

            //Realizamos el descifrado
            byte[] decryptedText = decryptionCipher.doFinal(encryptedText);

            cleartext =  new String(decryptedText); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return cleartext;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you encrypting if you are using SSL in the first place? HTTPS (SSL) will encrypt your data in transit, and it will be automatically decrypted on the server. Additionally, your custom encryption scheme is very likely to be less secure than SSL.

Your error is in how you derive your key: `setSeed()` does not replace the state of the random   number generator, it only augment it. What this means is that even if you pass the same bytes to `setSeed()`, `generateKey()` will most likely generate a different key. Use the [PBE](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html) (password-based encryption) classes to derive a key from a password. Or make sure your server and client are using the same key in some other way.

Here a sample of generating a key from a password (for Android). You need to find a PBE algorithm that is supported both on Android and on your server. If you use the JCE Bouncy Castle provider in your server app, it should support the same algorithms as Android (Android uses Bouncy Castle for part of its JCE implementation).

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = 
    SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec("password".toCharArray(), salt, 1024, 256);
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will test it

I want to encrypt the string becouse in Android, SSL/HTTPS it dosen´t work very well. I have to make a method to Trust all Host, so I want to encrypt it for extra security.

Thanks again

Comment: Do you have an example of using PBE?? please

Comment: You don't have to trust all hosts, you just have to install the server certificate into your application. How to do it has been answered a thousand times on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm working with that, but still have many problems

1) I takes a really long of time to generate the Secret and get the Cipher Instance

<code> 

SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM); 

</code> 

2) when I decrypt the String, the first 10 chars aprox are bad decrypted. The rest, 50 chars aprox are ok.

I update the question with my new code

Comment: Decrease the number of iterations and possibly use a shorter key. As for the decryption errors, you are using a random IV. You need to use the same IV for encryption and decryption.

Comment: Finally it works on Android App. I can encrypt and decrypt my xml string.

But now I Have a new problem. As I say upper, I sent the encrypted string to my server using HTTPS.

In the server, I need to decrypt the string, so I copy&paste my encrypt/decrypt class, and I try to used, but when I call decrypt method It show this Exception:

java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC SecretKeyFactory not available

I don´t know why. I check Java version (jdk1.6.0_26) and is ok

This code is like a nightmare for me.

Any idea?

Thanks again

Comment: As I said, you need to find an algorithm that is supported on both Android and server Java. Use the JCE Bouncy Castle provider in your server app, it should support the same algorithms as Android (Android uses Bouncy Castle for part of its JCE implementation).

Comment: How I use Bouncy Castle on my Java Server?. Do you have any idea?