# Encrypt zip file in java server and decrypt zip file in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption

I wrote the following code to encrypt a zip file in java server.

```
   public byte[] encrypt(byte[] skey, byte[] data){
      SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(skey, "AES");
      Cipher cipher;
      byte[] encrypted=null;
        try {
            // Get Cipher instance for AES algorithm
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");    
            // Initialize cipher
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            // Encrypt the image byte data
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
      return encrypted;
   }
```

This server sends this encrypted zip file to Android. Then, android decrypts it with following code.

```
public byte[] decrypt(byte[] skey, FileInputStream fis) {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(skey, "AES");
      Cipher cipher;
      byte[] decryptedData=null;
      CipherInputStream cis=null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");        
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            // Create CipherInputStream to read and decrypt the image data
            cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
            // Write encrypted image data to ByteArrayOutputStream
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[2048];
            while ((cis.read(data)) != -1) {
              buffer.write(data);
            }
            buffer.flush();         
            decryptedData=buffer.toByteArray();     
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                try {
                    fis.close();
                    cis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }      
      return decryptedData;
}
```

When I encrypt a plain zip file, this file 21 kb. Then, when I decrypt a encrypted zip file, zip file is 24 kb and it does not open in Android Phone. I tried some methods . Can I take your suggestions?

Thanks.

**EDIT: SOLVED**

I added iv parameter cipher.init() method:

```
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes));
 cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes));
```

I modified it with following code:

```
int numRead = 0;

while (numRead = cis.read(data)) != -1) {
     buffer.write(data, 0, numRead);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Encrypt String, send via HTTPS and Decrypt String problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181532/android-encrypt-string-send-via-https-and-decrypt-string-problem)

Comment: Two problems are immediately evident: 1) You haven't specified an IV,  and 2) you are not saving off and using the return value of `cis.read(data)` for the subsequent write.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Thank you your answer. :) I solve my problem. Then I will edit my question.